# Simple MAC converter

Tags: python, beginner

I'm new to Python and experimenting with some simple scripts. I would appreciate if you could give me some suggestions on how the following code can be improved or made simpler or anything in general.

```
#Coverts MAC Addresses into cisco format

def mac_conv(mac, sep='-'):
  #split mac address into 3 groups
  splitted_mac = mac.split(sep)
  gr1 = ''.join(splitted_mac[0:2])
  gr2 = ''.join(splitted_mac[2:4])
  gr3 = ''.join(splitted_mac[4:])

  #join groups into a single MAC
  mac = gr1, gr2, gr3
  final_mac = '.'.join(mac)

  #print final MAC address
  print(final_mac)

#Open file with MAC addresses and convert them
with open('mac.txt', 'r') as f:
  for mac in f.readlines():
    mac_conv(mac)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code's pretty good.
The *only* thing I'd change is to reduce the amount of lines.
To do this I would base my algorithm around the use of a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/comprehensions/737/list-comprehensions#t=201608061344140229773).

1. Split MAC into segments.
2. Slice segments into a three item list. (Like `gr1` without the join)
3. Perform a list comprehension to join the sliced segments together.
4. Join the new three item list together.
5. Return it.

```
segments = mac.split(sep)
groups = [segments[0:2], segments[2:4], segments[4:]]
a = [''.join(group) for group in groups]
mac = '.'.join(a)
return mac
```

I'd then join the last three lines into one.
As `return` and `'.'.join` are easy to understand in a single one-liner.

Other than the above function, you don't need to use `f.readlines()` you can just use `f`.
And you should *always* use four spaces.

This can result in:

```
def mac_conv(mac, sep='-'):
    segments = mac.split(sep)
    groups = [segments[0:2], segments[2:4], segments[4:]]
    return '.'.join(''.join(group) for group in groups)

with open('mac.txt', 'r') as f:
    for mac in f:
        print(mac_conv(mac))
```

Comment: your answer seems more understandable for me at the moment thanks.

Comment: Well, either four spaces or a tab. But no mixing both!.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you should be using `return` rather than `print` to get a value out of a function, otherwise you'll have problems when you try to expand the program.

```
def mac_conv(mac, sep='-'):

  #etc

  #return final MAC address
  return final_mac

#Open file with MAC addresses and convert them
with open('mac.txt', 'r') as f:
  for mac in f.readlines():
    print(mac_conv(mac))
```

I would also avoid reusing variables, especially if its a function argument (`mac`).  You can actually eliminate that usage of the variable all together:

```
#join groups into a single MAC
final_mac = '.'.join([gr1, gr2, gr3])
```

If I was writing this, however, I would probably do it in just a couple of lines, as you know exactly how the input and output strings are going to be formatted:

```
def mac_conv(mac, sep='-'):
    mac_parts = mac.split(sep)
    return "{0[0]}{0[1]}.{0[2]}{0[3]}.{0[4]}{0[5]}".format(mac_parts)
```

If this was going into a product, I would probably add some error handling too, to allow for input that isn't a mac address - too short, too long, wrong separators, alternate groupings (a cisco-formatted address is still a valid mac address, but this function won't handle it.)

Comment: why not use tuple unpacking: `return "{}{}.{}{}.{}{}".format(*mac.split(sep))`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't understand how does this part ""{0[0]}{0[1]}.{0[2]}{0[3]}.{0[4]}{0[5]}".format(mac_parts)" work though, because of my python knowledge so far.

Comment: @ErjolBane take a look at https://pyformat.info/, [specifically this section](https://pyformat.info/#getitem_and_getattr).

Answer (score 3):

#### Overall

Code seems fine - it works and is easy to comprehend.

#### Reusability

You `print` the result instead of `return`-ing it. If you wanted to do something else with MAC in that format (like printing it as a part of some string), what would you do?

#### Naming

There may be other formats for MAC addresses. If someone had successfully guessed that `mac_conv` converts MAC address, they'd still have to guess the format. `mac_to_cisco_format` is long, `mac_to_cisco` may be alright.

`separator` instead of `sep` may help *a little bit* to someone who only sees function's signature (as in many IDEs).

#### Documentation

`#Coverts MAC Addresses into cisco format` should be a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) instead.

`#print final MAC address` is just a visual garbage - next line is self-descriptive enough.

#### Algorithm

You assume some format of input data, while it's not spelled-out explicitly. While you could handle that with naming/documentation, you can change your algorithm to convert MACs from several formats to CISCO one - simply remove separators from strings (multiple `str.replace`-s will do) and then slice the result as you wish.

In fact, you could accept desired format as a parameter (instead of your `sep`).